# C++: elegant "polymorphism" with STL types and custom types?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, polymorphism

Let's say I have a custom implementation of `std::vector` named `my_vector`, and they have the same interface.

There are many functions that take `std::vector` (or its pointer/reference) as input. I want to make **as little modification as possible** to these functions, while allowing them to accept either `std::vector` or `my_vector`.

Replacing these functions with function templates is a way to go, but there seem to be a lot of change (and hence difficult to rollback), and they can't do type checking unless I use `std::is_same` to further complicate them. Function overloading is another alternative, but it entails duplicating the code, and is also difficult to rollback the change.

**Question**: can I design a wrapper type `Vector` for `std::vector` and `my_vector`, and let those functions accept `Vector` (or its pointer/reference) instead? But the problem with polymorphism is `std::vector` can't inherit a custom class.

Ideally, the code should similar to this (not required to be the same) :

Definition of function:

```
// void foo(std::vector<char> vec) {...} // old
void foo(Vector<char> vec) {...}  // new
```

Use the function:

```
std::vector<char> stdvec(5,'a');
my_vector<char> myvec(5,'a');
...

foo(stdvec);
foo(myvec);
```

Thanks!

PS1: accepting iterators instead of objects of containers is a good advice. However, there are some operations that cannot be achieved by iterators (like, `push_back()`, `resize()`, `reserve()`):

```
void extendVectorAndAddGarbage(std::vector<char> &vec) {
    size_t so=vec.size();
    vec.reserve(sz*100);
    for (size_t i=sz; sz<sz*100;++sz) {...}
}
```

PS2: the container might not be `std::vector` - I am asking about using "polymorphism" on a STL type and a custom type with the same interface.

PS3: don't hesitate to write answers if you think it is not achievable.

Comment: what functions specifically do you mean? All algorithms I know dont take vectors, but iterators as parameter

Comment: @tobi303 let's assume `my_vector` provides iterator types as well: `my_vector::iterator`, `my_vector::const_iterator`, etc.

Comment: if I understand you correctly its your own functions that you want to call, I dont see the problem with making those templated. You wont need to rollback, because even when templated you willl still have the same functions for `vector`, and the worries about  type checking unless you use std::is_same I dont understand

Comment: maybe you can expand your example to show why you think `template <typename T> void foo(T t)` would be problematic

Comment: @tobi303 explain what I meant with the type checking: say I use template function that takes template argument `T` (`T` should only be either `std::vector<char>` or `my_vector<char>`). But if I invoke the function with an instance of `std::list<char>` by mistake, there won't be a compilation error, unless the function body calls some methods `std::list` doesn't have.

Comment: well if there is no compilation error then most likely thats because the function also works for a `std::list`, if it doesnt you will get a compiler error. I would call it an advantage rather than a problem

Comment: Does your functions really need to take the container as a parameter?  Can you generalize it using iterators and then anything that has the right iterator type can be used?

Comment: i never tried it, but I am sure that there is a way that you can hide the template and only make the instantiation for `std::vector` and `my_vector` accesible, maybe that is what you want ?

Comment: Totally unclear what the problem is. You can have a templated function, or you can have iterators, or you can have overloads delegating to hidden templated functions - the world is your oyster.

Comment: @FilipKočica no, it doesn't:)

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, using iterators is a good way to go!

Comment: @tobi303 yes your reasoning makes sense..

Comment: @SergeyA all your suggestions seem to entail changing the functions substantially, but there are many of them - so I hope to avoid this.

Comment: If you don't want to change the functions too much then make a custom type trait call `is_vector` that is true for both types and then use `template<typename Cont, typename enable_if<is_vector<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>` as your template

Comment: you really should give a concrete code example. I am hesitating to write an answer, not because the answer is no, but because from your question it is not clear what is the problem you are trying to solve. You dont need lots of additional code (aka a wrapper) to call your functions with either a `std::vector` or a `my_vector`. Instead of your PS1 you should show a function that does resize or reserve.

Comment: @tobi303 ok I added an example. My point is, `std::vector` and `my_vector` have exactly the same interface, including but not limited to the same public member variables, methods, member typedefs, etc., so whatever operation that can be done on a `std::vector` should be applicable to `my_vector` as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: can I design a wrapper type Vector for std::vector and
>   my_vector, and let those functions accept Vector (or its
>   pointer/reference) instead? But the problem with polymorphism is
>   std::vector can't inherit a custom class.

I am really a fan of OO with inheritance and polymorphism and all that cool stuff, but even more I am a fan of not doing OO when I dont need to. Yes of course you can write a wrapper that lets you use whatever types polymorphically and you can use inheritance (even multiple if you want), but why would you? Do you really want to write all that boilerplate?

If you want minimum changes on existing code, like in

```
// void foo(std::vector<char> vec) {...} // old
void foo(Vector<char> vec) {...}  // new
```

then make it a template:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T vec) {...}
```

For your example, that would be

```
template <typename T> 
void foo(T &vec) {
    size_t so=vec.size();
    vec.reserve(sz*100);
    for (size_t i=sz; sz<sz*100;++sz) {...}
}
```

If you really want to prevent yourself from instantiating the template with something different than `std::vector` or `my_vector` then you could do for example this:

```
namespace {
    template <typename T> 
    void foo_impl(T& t) {
        size_t so=vec.size();
        vec.reserve(sz*100);
        for (size_t i=sz; sz<sz*100;++sz) {...}
    }
}

void foo(std::vector& t) { foo_impl(t);}
void foo(my_vector& t) { foo_impl(t);}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is go and write or get `gsl::span`.  A `gsl::span<const T>` is a top-notch replacement for a `std::vector<T,A> const&`.

The next thing you often want to do is to append data into a vector.

```
template<class T>
struct sink_t {
  using impl=std::function<void(T&&)>;
  impl fn;
  using res_fn=std::function<void(std::size_t)>;
  res_fn res;
  void reserve(std::size_t n) { if(res) res(n); }
  void push_back(T const& t) {
    push_back( T(t) );
  }
  void push_back( T&& t ) {
    fn(std::move(t));
  }
  void operator()(T&& t)const { push_back(std::move(t)); }
  sink_t(impl f, res r={}):fn(std::move(f)), res(std::move(r)) {}
  template<class A>
  sink_t( std::vector<T, A>& v ):
    fn(
      [&v](T&& tin){
        v.push_back( std::move(tin) );
      }
    ),
    res(
      [&v](std::size_t n){v.reserve(n);}
    )
  {}
  sink_t( my_vector<T>& v ):
    fn(
      [&v](T&& tin){
        v.push_back( std::move(tin) );
      }
    ),
    res(
      [&v](std::size_t n){v.reserve(n);}
    )
  {}
  sink_t( T& t ):
    fn( [&t]( T&& tin ) { t = std::move(tin); } )
  {}
  sink_t( T* t ):
    fn( t?impl([t]( T&& tin ) { *t = std::move(tin); }):impl() )
  {}
  explicit operator bool() const { return (bool)fn; }
};
```

now if you have code that shoves things into a `vector<T>` by `push_back`, have it instead take a `sink_t<T>`.

This, honestly, should deal with 99/100 reasonable cases.

The exception is if you have code that both reads and writes from a container, which is usually a bad sign.

In those cases, you could go and write a method-for-method vector type eraser.  But the cost to doing this is probably not worth it.

I'd propose that you use the above two techniques and see how much of your code becomes trivial to make flexible.

A `gsl::span<T>` is a view of (part of or a whole) contiguous buffer of `T`.  A `gsl::span<T const>` is basically all the parts of a `std::vector<T> const&` you care about without requiring that it be actually stored in a particular structure.

A `sink_t<T>` represents "a place to throw `T`s into".  I assume moving a `T` is cheap in the above code, and `std::function` has a touch more overhead than manual type erasure involving function pointers, but it should be pretty decent.  I gave it `.reserve` and `.push_back` because that should cover most of the code you want; you could add `.insert_back( Iterator, Iterator )` and `.move_into_back( Container&& )` and `.insert_back( Container const& )`, but I wouldn't add `.end()` as that is a pretty simple code transformation to replace `vec.insert( vec.end(), start, finish )` with `vec.insert_back( start, finish )`.

A final possibility is that your code is doing a `std::vector<T>& vec`, and all it does is *assign* to that `vec` (or clear it and assign to it).  That is a bit of code smell, but you can fix it by having a thin wrapper that takes a container, clears it, then passes it to a sink-based version of the function.

This is a technique I've used in my own code to abstract out "where I'm putting stuff".  It works reasonably well.

---

As an extra fun thing, if your have code that does pipeline processing like this:

```
template<class In, class Out>
using pipeline = std::function< void( In&&, sink_t<Out> ) >;
```

you can compose them

```
template<class In, class Out>
sink_t<In> operator|( pipeline<In, Out> pipe, sink_t<Out> sink ) {
  return
    [pipe=std::move(pipe), sink=std::move(sink)]( In&& in ){
      pipe( std::move(in), sink );
    };
}
template<class In, class Mid, class Out>
pipeline<In, Out> operator|( pipeline<In, Mid> lhs, pipeline<Mid, Out> rhs ) {
  return [lhs=std::move(lhs), rhs=std::move(rhs)]( In&& in, sink_t<Out>  sink){
    return lhs( std::move(in), std::move(rhs)|std::move(sink) );
  };
}
```

which is pretty fun.

Comment: Though it's not directly related.. upvote for the alternative approach! Actually I/m not really writing a `my_vector`.. it's just a thought experiment:)